# Post request going to Get function in WEB API in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a controller in the ASP.NET Web API. Below is the code for the controller

```
public class CalculateController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {

        return new string[] { "from get method" };

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Post([FromBody]string value)
    {

        return new string[] { "from post method" };
    }
}
```

Below is the code that I am using to make a post request to the webAPI

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:62479/api/calculate");

        StringBuilder postdata = new StringBuilder("value=Anshuman");
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata.ToString());
        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

The problem is that even if I make a **POST** request even then the data is returned from the **GET** method of the Controller. I have not made any changes in the default configuration of the Web API project. I am using MVC 4.

Thanks for your time. If any other information is required then please add a comment.

I have both the projects running in Visual Studio 2012 on the same machine.

Comment: Try explicitly providing action name -http://localhost:62479/api/calculate/Post

Comment: @malkam that does not work. Also the default URL Route configuration does not include action names in the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your post method without parameters.

by default it looks like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    //do something with data you posted
}
```

in your case, if you want return some string data:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return new string[] { "from post method" };
}
```

Just tested your code. It works fine, and post method hitted correctly. But in my case i got this in WebApiCOnfig.cs. It helps to make web api routing more flexible.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiGet", "api/{controller}", new { action = "Get" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPost", "api/{controller}", new { action = "Post" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiPut", "api/{controller}", new { action = "Put" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Put) });
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApiDelete", "api/{controller}", new { action = "Delete" }, new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Delete) });
```

Comment: I think the main point being, why is there a `POST` method which doesn't POST anything!?

Comment: I made the changes but still it hits the GET method. Updated the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: In addition I also had to upgrade web host package by 
using PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost

Answer (score 0):

You can add HttpPost and HttpGet action attributes to the relevant actions which will restrict the post from being directed to the get action by the routes